# The dreaded blue screen crash: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (cng.sys)

Tags: windows, crash, hyper-v, emulator

Don't even remember for how long but certainly from the days of Windows 8.1, I constantly get the SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (cng.sys) crash when booting from cold (doesn't happen on restart) but fortunately the OS recovers via a "bugcheck" restart as I see it logged in the Event Viewer. I searched and researched to fix this problem in the early days but no resolution and finally decided to live with it (yes, every cold boot has the blue screen crash, 100% guaranteed). Even a clean installation made no difference, be it Windows 8.1 or 10.

Today I had to sort out some issues with Windows phone emulators (in an attempt to use my new Windows 10 Mobile device). This led me to carry out some tests by disabling the Hyper-V machine used by the emulators (which is controlled via "Turn Windows feature on or off" under Programs and Features).

**It was an accidental discovery for me that the blue screen crash disappears when the Hyper-V machine is turned off!**

... which makes me conclude that, at least in my case, the SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (cng.sys) crash has to do with the Hyper-V virtual machine. My next speculation is perhaps how the Hyper-V interacts with the GPU (in my case nVidia GTX 560M) that could be the culprit but looks a good start in the right direction.

Having narrowed down the SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (cng.sys) crash to Hyper-V machine, does any body know how to fix this problem, or even suggest how to proceed for things to check out? It's really annoying to live with the blue screen crash.

Comment: http://www.tenforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/10555-bsod-system_service_exception-cng-sys-when-turning-laptop-3.html suggests it is caused by "fast boot". Try Control Panel-->Power Options-->Choose what the power buttons do click the words that say "change settings that are currently unavailable" and lastly uncheck the box that says "Turn on fast startup"

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I will test this and come back with a feedback.

But makes me wonder why someone down-voted me. Is this not a useful question? I find it bizarre and wish down-voting includes a comment why. 

@DaidPostill: I understand it wasn't you. You carried out your professional duty to help.

Comment: No idea. It wasn't me ;)

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\minidump. maybe we see more details.

Comment: @DaidPostill is **SPOT on**! Thank you so much, my problem is gone!. Please post as an answer so that I can mark it as answered. I am also curious as to the flaw in fast start-up that ends up in a crash: Is it some timing issue with memory, GPU ... what? Just wondered. Thanks again!

Comment: No, wait! The crash came back, be it with less frequency. I did about half a dozen cold reboots, mainly to test the blue screen crash and no crash, and today I switched on as normal to use it, and there it was. @magicandre1981: I have the MEMORY.DMP saved if it can be of any help. How can I post it, or perhaps put on my OneDrive public folder?

Comment: zip the dmp to reduce the zip, put the zip on your OneDrive, create a sharelink and post the share link here. I'll take a look at it with the debugger

Comment: have you uploaded the dmp files?

Comment: I started getting consistent Blue screens, I'm assuming that Hyper-V was secretly installed at some point. I removed it as suggested, and as far as I can tell, the problem has gone away.